# Multi-Field Query Result Sorting Issues (Access)

Tags: ms-access

Currently I have a query using multiple fields for user input in order to pull specific products based on the input entered. The goal is for the user to put in multiple analytes with the corresponding form, matrix and concentration they are searching for and for the query to populate lot numbers that include all or at minimum one. Now I was able to do that but I am wanting to tier the results so that the results that match the search criteria best are set at the top and it descends down from there with the lest relevant results. I've tried searching all throughout google and have watched multiple videos, but cannot seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to access so I apologize if my terminology is not up to par. I've posted the SQL code below and will provide any other info if need.

```
SELECT [MASTER PROMO].ID, 
       [MASTER PROMO].Lot, 
       [MASTER PROMO].[Exp Date], 
       [MASTER PROMO].Analyte, 
       [MASTER PROMO].Unit, 
       [MASTER PROMO].Matrix, 
       [MASTER PROMO].Form, 
       [MASTER PROMO].Concentration
FROM [MASTER PROMO]
WHERE ((([MASTER PROMO].Analyte) Like "*" & Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Analyte1 & "*" Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Analyte)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Analyte2 Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Analyte)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Analyte3 Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Analyte)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Analyte4) And 
       (([MASTER PROMO].Matrix) Like "*" & Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Matrix1 & "*" Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Matrix)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Matrix2 Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Matrix)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Matrix3 Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Matrix)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Matrix4) And 
       (([MASTER PROMO].Form) Like "*" & Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Form1 & "*" Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Form)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Form2 Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Form)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Form3 Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Form)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Form4) And 
       (([MASTER PROMO].Concentration) Like "*" & Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Concen1 & "*" Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Concentration)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Concen2 Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Concentration)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Concen3 Or 
        ([MASTER PROMO].Concentration)=Forms![Multi-Analyte Search Form]!Concen4));
```

Comment: I think this can be solved using custom VBA function, which accepts Analyte, Matrix, Form and Concentration as parameters and returns relevance rating or 0 if no matches. In the query filter and sort by results of this function.

Comment: Ok thank you! Do you happen to know of any good reference material for VBA? I've been attempting to look, but nothing seems to stand out that would help in figuring out how to code this properly. I don't have any prior experience with VBA.